# Text shadows and zooming

Tags: css, svg, d3.js

I'm trying to apply text shadows for svg text but it is kinda buggy for firefox and chrome but I'm not sure why. I'm trying to use them to create a border around the text.

Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f3m8Z/

And here is the css I'm using for text:

```
text-shadow: 0px -1px 5px red,     
     0px  1px 5px red,    
    -1px  0px 5px red,     
     1px  0px 5px red,    
    -1px -1px 5px red, 
    -1px  1px 5px red,     
     1px -1px 5px red,     
     1px  1px 5px red;
```

In Chrome if I zoom in and out some of the Hello Worlds have a thicker outline and if I drag it around it leaves behind text (if you zoom in first and then drag).

In Firefox only the top Hello World has some shadow (and it's not really even noticeable) but I read that Firefox does support text shadows.

Is the problem because the text is svg and not actual text and if so is there a workaround for this?

Thanks

Comment: You can also use an SVG Filter to apply a shadow to SVG text

Answer (score 0):

SVG text does [not support text-shadow](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/propidx.html). The good news is that this is something that will probably be added to SVG 2 and so it will be supported at some point in the future.

One workaround would be to use `<foreignObject>` to embed html text, but that won't work in IE9 or IE10 as neither supports `<foreignObject>`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to create a border round the text, you could just apply a stroke.  The disadvantage is that it would encroach on the fill of the text. But the way around that would be to overlay two copies of the text. The one underneath would have the red stroke and the front one would have no stroke.

This solution is not quite as clean as a CSS shadow, but it would achieve the effect you want.